# window.open() shows same .html

Tags: javascript

so first of all, I am new with GCP and web application development, please don't go to hard on me :). So I am trying to open a new popup/tab window with the content of an html that has been uploaded to the server when I deploy the app. Problem is that I know how to open a new URL, but do not really know how to open an html file from my server directory.

I have tried the below code, and the popup window opens, although it opens the same html as my index.html (main page). Do you know why this happens? any other tips to do what I am doing would also be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

```
<button onclick="visual_window('FSCVisual.html')">Try it</button>

<script>
function visual_window(url) {
  var myvisualWindow = window.open(url, "myvisualwindow", "width=1000,height=1200");

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try providing the full url of the html file you want to open, something like:

```
<button onclick="visual_window('http://www.somedomain.com/FSCVisual.html')">Try it</button>
```

Comment: It gives the same result, it only opens a new window with the same html as index.html. The thing is it works fine when I deploy the app locally with XAMPP, but it does not work when I deploy it with Google Cloud Platform.. So it must be something to do with the server directory or something... Thank you!